# How to debug Total Commander buttons which open a command shell?

Tags: total-commander

I have a custom button in Total Commander which runs some executable which runs in the command shell (`wget.exe` in my case, but that is not important). The command shell disappears as soon as the process exits, so if there is an error, it is impossible to read. What is the most elegant way around that?

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix the command with `%COMSPEC% /K` to keep the shell open.